# How do I successfully build monaco-editor in esbuild?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, esbuild

I have tried the same configuration on different platforms and they all work, while in esbuild it leads to an error

esbuild:

```js
esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js'],
  outfile: outfile,
  bundle: true,
  format: 'iife'
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Build complete, save at ' + outfile)
})
```

I then referenced it in the project as follows

```js
self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  getWorker() {
    return new Worker('/assets/editor.worker.js')
  },
}
import(
  'monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/typescript/typescript.contribution'
).then(() => {
  import('monaco-editor').then(({ editor }) => {
    editor.create(container.current, {
      language: 'typescript',
    })
  })
})
```

Eventually the console reports a runtime error and I find that the worker file has been referenced correctly and the error seems to be due to walking this code

```js
if (!initialized) {
  initialize(null);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

I just need to change the directory of the imported editors to api

```js
import('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api').then(({ editor }) => {
  editor.create(container.current, {
    language: 'typescript',
  })
})
```